# Don't forward to another page

Tags: java, servlets

I have a question regarding a doPost method.
I have made doPost method that executes a query on a db.

code:

```
try{


         Statement st1 = con.createStatement();

        PreparedStatement ps1=con.prepareStatement("INSERT into nota (Id_utilizator,Nume_reteta,Nota) values ((SELECT Id_user from user where E_mail = '"+request.getSession().getAttribute("email")+"'),(SELECT Nume FROM reteta where Nume = '"+retetaidd+"'),('"+nota+"'))");
         ps1.executeUpdate();

        response.sendRedirect(request.getRequestURI());   

        st1.close();
        con.close();
        ps1.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e2)
    {
      e2.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now I want that when my query is executed the page don't redirect to another page, I want to stay on the same page and the query to be executed.
I know that I should replace

`request.getRequestDispatcher("/health.jsp").forward(request, response);`

but I don't know with what.Could anyone help me?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute the query without page reload then you can use AJAX. Otherwise you can use `RequestDispatcher` like this way

```
request.setAttribute("AttributeName", "AttributeValue");
request.getRequestDispatcher("/health.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Here health.jsp is the same page from where request comes and to where request goes.

Comment: how can I integrate ajax into my code to do what i want?I don't know so much about ajax.Thanks

Comment: @Bogdan Have a look at the answer for ajax call http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax?rq=1

Comment: I managed to do something,but now I have another probelm:( please look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905594/ajax-submit-for-all-forms

Comment: I have answered the question. IF it works then please accept the answers for both the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HttpServletrequest.getRequestURI](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) for redirecting same page

```
httpResp.sendRedirect(httpReq.getRequestURI());
```

### UPDATE1:

Then set your necessary data in your request scope and use forward() method of your RequestDispatcher for controlling your desired JSP.

```
request.setAttribute("results", results);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

For full demonstration, go to [Servlet Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Credit goes to @[BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)

Comment: Changed as you said but it seems that is redirecting me to another page,is not staying on the same page.

Comment: @Bogdan I have updated my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is just put code below replacing `response.sendRedirect(request.getRequestURI());`

```
String previousURL = request.getHeader("referer");
response.sendRedirect(previousURL);
```

This might solve your problem